# How do I convert String date to Date format date in dd-MM-yyyy format in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have date in string format as Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 IST 2023 but I want it as in dd-mm-yyyy format in DATE type only... I can convert it but it is converting in String type I want it should convert it into ONLY Date type in dd-mm-yyyy format.

I tried below code but it is converting in String format as Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 IST 2023 but I want output should be something like

Date date = 07-06-2023 only.

Please help me.

My code snippet is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
String dateOfBirht= "07-06-2023";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateOfBirht);
System.out.println(date);
```

If you see the output of the above code snippet is printing as `Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 IST 2023` which is not my desired answer. It should be `07-06-2023` in **DATE FORMAT ONLY** **neither String nor LocaleDate**

Comment: Don't use ancient date classes `java.time.LocalDate` is what you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *"... I want it as in dd-mm-yyyy format in DATE type only. ..."*

I'm not sure I understand the question, entirely.  You already have the *Date* value,  here.

```java
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateOfBirht);
```

> *"... If you see the output of the above code snippet is printing as `Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 IST 2023` which is not my desired answer. It should be `07-06-2023` ..."*

I believe you're implying that the *Date* object should not be returning the time, since you had only parsed the date values.

This isn't the case.  Similarly, it is still a valid date; the zeroed time fields should play no role in the date fields.

Nevertheless, you can use a basic *String* format.
Format specifiers can be found on the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dt)* class JavaDoc.

```java
System.out.printf("%td-%1$tm-%1$tY", date);
```

Output

```
07-06-2023
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the Java.util.Date class does not have a specific format associated with it. Printing a Date object uses the default format provided by the toString() method.

To display the date in the desired format (dd-mm-yyyy) without any time or timezone information, you can use the java.text.SimpleDateFormat class to format the date as a string and then parse it back into a Date object.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateOfBirth = "07-06-2023";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
```

Note that the java.util.Date class is outdated, and it's recommended to use the newer java.time API introduced in Java 8 for date and time manipulation. However, if you specifically need to work with the Date class, the above approach will work fine.

Comment: Likely to be a copy-paste from ChatGPT

Answer (score 2):

Avoid old date classes, so:

```
String s = "Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 IST 2023";
DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.UK);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, dtf1);
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.UK);
String s2 = dtf2.format(zdt.toLocalDate());
System.out.println(s2);
```

Any date type, including `java.util.Date` is essentially a number internally. Like `int`, they don't have formats.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8+, you really should be leveraging the `java.time` classes for any date functionality.

But to answer your question, you need to use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat#format` to convert the legacy Date to any format you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateOfBirth = "07-06-2023";
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
}
```